# Django application not working after moving to different directory

Tags: django

I have a `Django 2.0` project with following structure and it's working fine

```
app_dir
 |- myapp
    |- settings
       |- __init__.py
       |- local.py
       |- production.py
    |- __init__.py
    |- wsgi.py
    |- urls.py
 |- other_app
    |- templates
       |- other_app
          |- index.html
    |- models.py
    |- views.py
    |- urls.py
 |- manage.py
 |- static_resources # directory just to keep core files which are not used in application
 |- .gitignore
 |- .dockerignore
 |- Dockerfile
 |- docker-compose.yml
 |- Pipfile
 |- Pipfile.lock
 |- Procfile
 |- requirements.txt
 |- start.sh
 |- db.sqlite3
```

as you can see `Django` applications and other files which are not directly used in application are all at the same level.

So, I thought to move `Django applications` to `src` directory to make it separate from other files which are of no use or are auto created.

My new directory structure looks like

```
app_dir
 |- src
    |- myapp
       |- settings
          |- __init__.py
          |- local.py
          |- production.py
       |- __init__.py
       |- wsgi.py
       |- urls.py
    |- other_app
       |- templates
          |- other_app
             |- index.html
       |- models .py
       |- views.py
       |- urls.py
    |- manage.py
 |- static_resources # directory just to keep core files which are not used in application
 |- .gitignore
 |- .dockerignore
 |- Dockerfile
 |- docker-compose.yml
 |- Pipfile
 |- Pipfile.lock
 |- Procfile
 |- requirements.txt
 |- start.sh
 |- db.sqlite3
```

**But now this is not detecting other applications installed or created.**

Here is my `settings/local.py` which was working earlier

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    #####################
    # created apps
    #####################
    'other_app',

    ####################
    # installed apps
    ####################
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'koober.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_my_project')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'static_root')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

and giving error

[image]

`socialaccount` is a template_tag by `allauth` which is installed

I think appending `src.` to all imports might work, but since there are many applications already created adding `src.` to each import is quite difficult.

Is there any other way I can run the application with the new directory structure and without adding `src.` to all the imports? (*if required, directory structure can be changed*)

Comment: Have you tried src.other_app as the entry in installed apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding 'allauth.socialaccount' to INSTALLED_APPS? The example settings on the Allauth project's github include this. [github-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py)